# Germany Blue Card change job/employer

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, eu, blue-card

So it has been almost 6 months in Germany with my first job here on the Blue Card. Now I accepted another better offer which wants me to start on Apr 1. So I'm currently in my 2 week notice period with the current company and the last day is Mar 21. I've searched online so hard and also on the berlin service website - there's just no proper instructions on how to change the employer. I know I have to notify ABH but when and how? On my green paper (Zusablatt) there is only mention of my designation/role, there is NO mention of the current company.

1. Which ABH office should I go to? Keplerstrasse or the other one? Or BIS which issued my blue card?
2. How should I get the appointment? I don't see any online appointment facility for this purpose in any offices. Can I just walk-in and take a token?
3. When should I do this? I just signed the new contract offer yesterday and I'm still in my 2 week notice period with current company. Should I go to the ABH/BIS only after my last day in current company or can I do it right-away and still serve notice period?
4. Do I have to get this done and only then start at the new place or can this be done in parallel (join anyway on Apr 1 and get this done then or later asap)?
5. I believe my TK insurance will be valid without extra cost for 1 month more from my current company's last date. So I guess I should be fine with TK when switching jobs. Please confirm?

Thanks! Hoping to hear from others who have switched before 2 years in Germany.